# Where to stand to throw circles over sticks

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Consider a horizontal line with vertical lines centered on the x-axis and placed at gaps of \$\sqrt{2}/2\$.  For a positive integer \$n \geq 3\$, the first half of the lines have lengths \$0, \sqrt{2}, 2\sqrt{2}, 3\sqrt{2}, \dots, (n-1)\sqrt{2}\$ and then the second half have lengths \$(n-2)\sqrt{2}, (n-3)\sqrt{2}, \dots, 0\$.

The goal is to find a circle center on the horizontal line so that for every pair of consecutive vertical lines, there exists a circle with that center which fits between them  without touching either of them. For example, in the following illustration we can see that if we picked the origin for \$n=3\$ and  the center at the origin, it is possible.

[image]

For \$n = 4\$, we can see that the center can't be at the origin.

[image]

We instead will need to move the center to the left. If we move the center to -1, then it is just possible.

[image]

For \$n=5\$ a center at -1 doesn't work and neither does -2.

[image]

For \$n=5\$ the desired output is -3.

## Task

Given an integer \$n \geq 3\$, output the largest integer valued circle center \$ x
\leq 0\$ so that there exists a circle with that center for each pair vertical lines that goes between the vertical lines and doesn't touch them.

Comment: Any counterexample where the longest one isn't bottleneck?

Comment: @l4m2 It's a great question. I don't have a counterexample but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 24 bytes

```javascript
n=>(n*4-2-n*n)/8**.5-1|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbDkAwEAXQ7Uynhnolkqq9CCpE7gjiy97rnH18x3u6tvMR6LykGBLCQOBGKgHDFB1z3kr5uRT1IoTaoy@d89bCTIpbjyU/dCVkkWBM@gE)

> Any counterexample where the longest one isn't bottleneck?

Looks correct. Proof: scale the circle smaller and see how the allowed distance also get smaller

[Used WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x-1%29%5E2%2B%28n-1%29%5E2%3D%28x%29%5E2)

Comment: You're the best golfer there ever was!

Comment: I hope someone is able to prove this correct.